# understand syntax in the sml language

Tags: function, syntax, sml

Hello I started to write in sml and I have some difficulty in understanding a particular function.

I have this function:

```
fun isInRow (r:int) ((x,y)) = x=r;
```

I would be happy to get explain to some points:

1. What the function accepts and what it returns.
2. What is the relationship between `(r: int)` `((x, y))`.

Thanks very much !!!

Answer (score 3):

The function `isInRow` has two arguments. The first is named `r`. The second is a pair `(x, y)`. The type ascription `(r: int)` says that r must be an int.

This function is curried, which is a little unusual for SML. What this means roughly speaking is that it accepts arguments given separately rather than supplied as a pair.

So, the function accepts an int and a pair whose first element is an int. These are accepted as separate arguments. It returns a boolean value (the result of the comparison `x = r`).

A call to the function would look like this:

```
isInRow 3 (3, 4)
```

There is more to say about currying (which is kind of cool), but I hope this is enough to get you going.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Jeffrey has said,

- You don't need the extra set of parentheses:

  ```
  fun isInRow (r:int) (x,y) = x=r;
  ```
- You don't need to specify the type `:int`. If you instead write:

  ```
  fun isInRow r (x,y) = x=r;
  ```

  then the function's changes type from ***int → (int • 'a) → bool*** into ***''a → (''a • 'b) → bool***, meaning that `r` and `x` can have any type that can be compared for equality (not just int), and `y` can still be anything since it is still disregarded.

  Polymorphic functions are one of the strengths of typed, functional languages like SML.
- You could even refrain from giving `y` a name:

  ```
  fun isInRow r (x,_) = x=r;
  ```